# Why is my vector rotation function changing the vector's magnitude?

Tags: c++, vector, rotation, 2d, linear-algebra

I'm looking to make a simple function that rotates a vector's point b around point a for a given number of degrees.

What's odd is that my code seems to work somewhat - the vector is rotating, but it's changing length pretty drastically.

If I stop erasing the screen every frame to see every frame at once, I see the lines producing a sort of octagon around my origin.

[image]

Even weirder is that the origin isn't even in the center of the octagon - it's in the bottom left.

Here's my code:

```
struct Point { int x, y; };

struct Line { 
    Point a, b; 
    void rotate(double);
};

void Line::rotate(double t)
{
    t *= 3.141592 / 180;

    double cs = cos(t);
    double sn = sin(t);

    double trans_x = (double)b.x - a.x;
    double trans_y = (double)b.y - a.y;

    double newx = trans_x * cs - trans_y * sn;
    double newy = trans_x * sn + trans_y * cs;

    newx += a.x;
    newy += a.y;

    b.x = (int)newx;
    b.y = (int)newy;
}
```

Using the olc::PixelGameEngine to render, which is why I'm using ints to store coordinates.

Comment: Don't store the points as integer. You will just lose too much precision. You can convert them to `int` when issuing the draw command, but you should keep them as `double` or `float` internally.

Comment: Hey that worked - thank you! It's crazy how many weird effects type safety issues can have.

Comment: It's not a type safety issue, it's rounding. Basically your program changes the length after every rotation, which might be okay if you only do one rotation, but if you do a whole bunch then you have problems.

Comment: You should not store the rotated coordinates but rotate your originals further and further, as otherwise you will accumulate rounding errors. Store the rotation so you can increment it.